# How to cancel doInBackground in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Here is my Code:

```
class XMLDownload extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            URL url = urls[0];
            XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = xmlParser.getXMLFromUrl(url);

            Document doc = xmlParser.getDomElement(xml);
            if (doc == null){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Falsche URL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  
            } else {
                writeToFile(xml, "xmlfilesnames" + ".kx_todo");
                [...]
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> xmlItems) {
        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            CustomAdapterProjects adapter = new CustomAdapterProjects(ListViewActivity.context, projectItems);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

If the User gives the wrong URL and `doc` is null. Then i want to show a Toast.

I've read some other Threads about canceling the `AsyncTask` but this is more unique because i have a NPE INSIDE the `doInBackground` method and not else where.

How can i cancel the `doInBackground` method. It makes no sense to continue the method. Otherwise i get a lot of NPE (NullPointerException).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (doc == null) {
  return null;
}
```

and `onPostExecute` check if `xmlItems`  is null. If it is null show the `Toast`

Comment: My question is how to cancel the doInBackground method from going on. If it continoues i got more and more NPE because of the doc == null... If i return null... doesn't my app crash?

Comment: if doc is null and you return, the execution flow continues from onPostExecute. There check if the parameter is null. It is null show the toast and do nothing else. And, please, remove the Toast from doInBackground

Answer (score 1):

> How can i cancel the doInBackground method. It makes no sense to continue the method. Otherwise i get a lot of NPE (NullPointerException).

You can cancel your `AsyncTask` by simply calling `xMLDownload.cancel(true);`.

Comment: When you are creating an object of your asynctask like `XMLDownload xMLDownload = new XMLDownload();  xMLDownload.execute();` so make this `xMLDownload` instance variable. Whenever you want to cancel your asynctask then call `xMLDownload.cancel(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just return null if `url` or `doc` any of them is null.

```
if(doc == null || url == null){
  return null;
}
```

and then in `onPostExceute` you can do whatever you want to do.

Comment: If you return `null` the execution would come to `onPostExecute` method where you can check if your `Arraylist` parameter is null or not and then on the basis of that you can implement your code.